# Determine the real coefficients of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I need to determine the real coefficients $a, b, c$ of the following polynomial: 
$$P(x) = x^5 + ax^4 - 2x^3 - 6x^2 + bx + c$$

I know that $P(-2) = 9$, and *the sum of the solutions (roots of the polynomial) is 3*, and *so is the product*. I'm not sure if these last two conditions are correct, they sound like a typo?

Then I need to write the given polynomial by degrees of $(x - 1)$.

Now, I've tried going this way:

If $P(-2) = 9$, then
$$16a - 2b + c = 37$$

As far as I know, a quintic polynomial should have 5 real solutions? Therefore,
$$x_1 \times  x_2 \times  x_3 \times  x_4 \times  x_5  = 3$$ and
$$x_1 +  x_2 +  x_3 +  x_4 +  x_5  = 3$$

But where do I go from here? How do I formulate this into something that will probably result in a system of two equations with $a, b, c$? Then I can solve them with the first one.

Answer (score 1):

By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we have
$$\text{sum of the roots}=-\frac{a}{1}=3\quad\text{and}\quad \text{product of the roots}=-\frac{c}{1}=3\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Sum of the roots is basically $-a=3$, and the product is basically $-c=3$.

Hence $b={-48-3-37\over2}=-44$.

Comment: "basically"?...